# How many times can we upload iOS app in TestFlight with out uploading App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

We are uploading iOS app in TestFlight around 10 times, but we are not uploading upto now in App Store. Because of our app is not public app only for few people. We tried a lot to get Enterprise edition to distribute our app with in the organisation. But apple rejected for Enterprise edition. So thats way we are using TestFlight. I know latest TestFlight app has upto 90 days for single build. My final question is How many months or years we can survive in TestFlight with out uploading App Store ?.

Can i know the TestFlight upload builds restrictions, means number of total builds to upload TestFlight with out uploading app store and number of moths or years to survive with out uploading App Store.

Comment: There is  no such a limit mentioned in TestFlight doc. I already uploaded 8 versions.

Comment: @ ivarun Thank you. From last 6 months on words I'm using, can I use one more year...

Comment: Yes, you can upload.

Comment: @  ivarun, thank you very much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a limit mentioned in TestFlight Doc. I have already uploaded 8 build for my one of the app.

Comment: We have an app at 915 builds over about one year without a release to the App Store, for any one wondering if double or triple digits pose a problem.

Answer (score 3):

i Have upload 83 build in test flight without uploading in Appstore.

Comment: I'm using TestFlight for last 4 years. SO, I think there is no limit for upload builds.

Comment: @ Sagar Bhut. with out uploading in App Store are you using same app from last 4 years or different apps .

Answer (score 2):

Here is all you need to know about testflight

**NOTE**: you can upload **as many as versions to testflight** for an app for testing purpose, Each app can be tested by up to 25 members, each member can test on up to 30 devices.

**Overview**

To take advantage of TestFlight, simply upload a beta build of your app, and use App Store Connect to add the names and email addresses of people you’d like to test your app. Testers will install the TestFlight app for iOS, watchOS, and tvOS so they can use your beta apps and quickly provide feedback.

**Internal Testers**

Each app can be tested by up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Admin, App Manager, Developer, or Marketer role in App Store Connect. Each member can test on up to 30 devices. Internal testers can access all of your beta builds available for testing.

**External Testers and Groups**

Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 10,000 external testers who do not need to be part of your team to beta test an app that you intend for public release on the App Store. You can organize external testers into custom groups and share different builds with each group, depending on which features you want them to test. Before external testing can begin, the app must pass Beta App Review to make sure it complies with the full App Store Review Guidelines. Only the first build for the beta version requires a full review.

**Supported Apps**

Up to 100 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally, and builds remain active for 90 days after they are uploaded. TestFlight supports multiple builds of iOS apps, watchOS apps, tvOS apps, and iMessage apps at the same time

Comment: i have uploaded 26 build for test purpose so far as beta version , which is used only for testing purpose...versions are in the sequence of 1.0.0 ,1.0.1 and so on...indicates minor changes...